# View contents of a ICO container file on macOS

Tags: macos, icon

ICO file extension is a [container file format](http://fileformats.wikia.com/wiki/Icon) that may include several icon images of different sizes. I'd like to know how I may access and view what is inside a ICO file, i.e. the different images it contains, and possibly any metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in Preview.app can handle ICO files and show the contents of the container. It can also show the file metadata. To view file metadata, use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

[image]

Right click on one of the images, select Export As... and select the desired format.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thank you, Nimesh. I would have a subsidiary question: why, when I right-click on the ICO icon in the Finder, don't I see 'Show Contents'?

Comment: @OlivierdeBroqueville Because ICO file is not formatted as [macOS bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)).